# How to get the current worksheet gid?

Tags: python, url, gspread, pygsheets

I use Python and Gspread to create a gsheet with about 40 worksheet containing datas about accounts.
On the first worksheet, I want to put something like a summary with a link to the account's worksheet with something like =LIEN_HYPERTEXTE("#gid=xxxxxxxxxxxx","Account_42") but for this i need the worksheet gid/url.
I've tried things with gspread or with pygsheets but the only thing i get is the worksheet id.

Is there a simple way to get it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the sheet IDs and sheet names in the Spreadsheet.

  - You want to retrieve the sheet IDs of 40 sheets in the created Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? `GID` is the sheet ID of a sheet in a Spreadsheet. This is the same with the worksheet ID using at gspread.

In order to retrieve all worksheet IDs in a Spreadsheet, I think that the method of `worksheets()` can be used.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet Id.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sh = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
worksheet_list = sh.worksheets()
for sheet in worksheet_list:
    print('sheetName: {}, sheetId(GID): {}'.format(sheet.title, sheet.id))
```

- In this script, it supposes that you have already used `credentials`.

#### Reference:

- [Selecting a Worksheet](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#selecting-a-worksheet)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: That's perfect, I found something with worksheet_list too but I needed to regex it after.
TY

Comment: @Corentin LEGROS Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.